# MemoryCache.Add returns true but does not add item to cache

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add items to the MemoryCache.Default instance using the Add method as below:

```
bool result= MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, dataToCache, cacheItemPolicy)
```

The value of result is true, indicating that the item has been added to the cache yet when I attempt to retrieve it immediately afterwards the cache is empty. I have also tried to add the item using the Set method with the same result of an empty cache.

The cache has the default 99Mb memory limit so it doesn't appear as if there is no space to add new items.

Any ideas?

---

```
private static void InsertCachedData(string cacheKey, object dataToCache, string[] dependantCacheKeys)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();

        cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now, new TimeSpan(hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 3600));

        if (dependantCacheKeys != null && dependantCacheKeys.Length > 0)
        {
            cacheItemPolicy.ChangeMonitors.Add(MemoryCache.Default.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(dependantCacheKeys));
        }

        MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, dataToCache, cacheItemPolicy);

        logger.DebugFormat("Cache miss for VehiclesProvider call with key {0}", cacheKey);
    }
```

Comment: What settings is `cacheItemPolicy` using?

Comment: +3,600 seconds & absoluteExpiration = true.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're not setting the `AbsoluteExpiration` property correctly.

The `TimeSpan` argument that you pass to the [`DateTimeOffset` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980.aspx) should be the offset from UTC of the passed `DateTime` value, *not* some arbitrary timespan that you want to add to generate your offset. You're passing in 3600 seconds -- ie, one hour -- which is working purely by coincidence because, presumably, you're based in the UK where BST is currently one hour ahead of UTC.

You're passing `DateTime.Now` as the `DateTime` argument, so what you're effectively doing is setting the cached item to expire immediately.

If you want your cached item to live for an hour then set the expiration like this:

```
cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));
```

Comment: I would suggest using DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1). DateTime.Now is slow because of needing to calculate the local time, and MemoryCache ignores local time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are setting the policy's `AbsoluteExpiration` to a zero, or very small,  `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: It's set to +3,600 seconds so shouldn't be that.

Comment: The `Add` overload in your original question appears not to exist. Is it definitely correct?

Comment: The overload does exist, it has a 4th optional argument that I have not passed.

Comment: OK by "when I attempt to retrieve it immediately afterwards the cache is empty" I assume you mean the object you get back is null? Is it possible the object you added happened to be null?

Comment: The object I added is not null, MemoryCache does not allow the addition of null objects and throws an exception when you try to add one. No such exception occurs and I can see that the object I am adding is not null in debug mode.

Once added, the method returns true but the base IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> in which the items usually get stored is empty when I enumerate it which suggests to me that is hasn't been added, despite the method returning a value to indicate that it has.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the exact code for the storage and subsequent lookup?

Comment: Sure, have added it to bottom of original question.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the default cache is not properly configured in the application's `app.config`. Otherwise I'm at a bit of a loss: one other experiment could be to temporarily remove the change monitor code in case that is messing up somehow (though can't see how).

Comment: Have tried all those things to no avail, thankf for the suggestions though.

Comment: One more thought: it's not possible you're specifying the group in the lookup code is it (the optional fourth parameter)?

Comment: I'm not, I am looking for the items in the same cache (MemoryCache.Default).